# Android 4.4: how to select and change the default sms Application without running it

Tags: android, sms

```
What I want
```

To show a dialog with the installed **"sms App"** as choice list.
The result of user action will change the default sms app without running the selected Sms application.

```
I've tried:
```

- a chooserIntent but that runs the Sms App.
- mActivity.startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS)) but no input for sms app

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to set a default SMS app that is not your own? Android does currently allow you to arbitrarily set the default SMS handler programmatically (though it queries the user first). This means that if you can't find a baked-in chooser to switch the default (you might be able to do that by using an undocumented Intent into the settings), you could probably construct your own chooser that gives you the package name of the app to set as the default. Then you would just follow the instructions [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html) to change the default SMS app.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to manage the specific error case of loosing the old package name. I know how to get the list of "sms app" package name  but not how to show them with the icon !

Comment: of loosing? Loosing what?